# NO SOUND. Ubuntu 15.10.INTEL AUDIO DRIVER VIA VT1708S

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound, audio-jack, hda-intel

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 32 bit. my computer's audio isn't working, no sound at all.I have checked my speakers & that the system isn't muted. I have Intel audio driver VIA VT1708S.
.I have just installed Ubuntu and i don't know much of the commands. help me  in a detailed step by step command.

Comment: check if your user is in audio group, if not add your user to the group, logout and login again.

Comment: // , I can confirm that Ubuntu 16.04 has this problem on XPS L512x. 14.04 did not have this problem on XPS L512x. Also, for better visibility, you should rewrite this as a *question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the terminal and start alsamixer using the following command:

```
alsamixer
```

You don't need to install any software for using alsamixer
Then press F6 to select a sound card.
Try any of the sound cards
Inside a sound card you will see many devices such as headphones,etc.
Try increasing(using arrow up/down key) the value of each device(select device using side-arrows) until you get your sound.

Comment: // , You have to use the right and left arrows to select any speakers that have no colors on their bar, and press the up arrow. This worked as a workaround for https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1622844